# Jagged edges on rotated images in HTML canvas after updating to Firefox 44.0

Tags: html, firefox, canvas

After updating my Firefox to version 44.0 Images that are rotated in a html5 canvas appear with jagged edges. I'm on a Mac OSX. Any ideas?

Here is my example code

```js
    window.onload = function() {
      var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      var img = document.getElementById("scream");
      ctx.rotate(0.5);
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 250);
    };
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #D4D4D4
}
#scream {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#canvas {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="250"></canvas>
<p>
  <img id="scream" src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/people-q-c-300-250-9.jpg" alt="The Scream" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This indeed looks like a bug in Firefox's anti-aliasing algorithm used by `drawImage` method.

Unfortunately, I can still reproduce it in FF 45.0b1, and in FF 47.0a1 it got generalized to the `fillRect` method too.
<sup>(all the tests were made on mac)</sup>

I filled a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1245061) on mozilla's bugzilla.

An other snippet for FF < 45 :

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// create a buffer canvas
var can = c.cloneNode(true);
var x = can.getContext('2d');
x.fillStyle = ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
x.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 250);

ctx.rotate(0.5);
ctx.drawImage(can, 0, 0, can.width, can.height)

btn.onclick = function(){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
  if(this.innerHTML.indexOf('drawImage')>0){
    // draw the buffer canvas
    ctx.drawImage(can, 0, 0, can.width, can.height);
    this.innerHTML = "use fillRect method";
    
    }
  else{
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
    this.innerHTML = "use drawImage method";
    }
  };
```

```css
button{vertical-align : top}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="250"></canvas>
<button id="btn">use fillRect method</button>
```